# Strange proposition in probability book for conditional probability

Tags: probability, proof-writing

I found the following proposition (15.1) in the probability book of Heinz Bauer:

> Let us given that $X$ is a numeric random variable on
>   $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ which is non-negative / integrable. Then to
>   any sub-algebra $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathcal{A}$ it exists a almost
>   surly unique non-negative / integrable random variable $X_0$, which is
>   $\mathcal{C}$ measurble and it holds $$ \int_C X_0 \,dP = \int_C X \,dP
>  \quad \text{for all }C\in \mathcal{C}.$$ When $X$ is integrable and
>   non-negative, then $X_0$ is almost surly non-negative.

I do not get the addition at the end

> When $X$ is integrable and
>   non-negative, then $X_0$ is almost surly non-negative.

Isn't that already clear? Because part of the above statement is if $X \geq 0 \, \Rightarrow \, X_0 \geq 0 $? I think he is actually proving the same statement twice in one proof with different techniques - or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what is meant where it says "non-negative/integrable" twice, it means that if $X$ is non-negative then $X_0$ is non-negative (and both might fail to be integrable) and which $X$ is integrable then $X_0$ is integrable (and both might fail to be non-negative).  If that is what was intended, then the last statement is redundant.  It's not "already clear" in the sense of requiring no proof, but it's already stated earlier in the proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Being familiar with Bauer's notation from his book on Measure Theory, I believe Bauer wants to make the following distinction:

For a numerical (meaning extended real-valued for Bauer) non-negative (everywhere!) random variable $X$ (for such $X$ the integral always exist in $[0,\infty]$), Bauer defines the conditional expectation $X_0$ as a non-negative (everywhere!) numerical random variable which is $\mathcal{C}$ measurable and has the property

$$\int_C X_0 \,dP = \int_C X \,dP
 \quad \text{for all }C\in \mathcal{C}.$$

Such an $X_0$ exists (by the first part of the proof) and is $P$-a.s. unique, in the sense that if $X'_0$ is another non-negative (everywhere!) $\mathcal{C}$ measurable numerical random variable with the above property then $X=X_0$ $P$-a.s.

The requirement that $X_0$ be non-negative everywhere comes from the first part of the proof, which involves the existence of a density from the Radon-Nikodym theorem, and Bauer defines a density to be non-negative everywhere. Essentially this is the standard machinery in Lebesgue integration: you start with non-negative functions, and then for signed functions you consider the positive and negative parts. Hence the first part of the proof is a preliminary step for the following general case:

For a numerical (meaning extended real-valued) integrable  random variable $X$, Bauer defines the conditional expectation $X_0$ as a numerical integrable random variable which is $\mathcal{C}$ measurable and has the property

$$\int_C X_0 \,dP = \int_C X \,dP
 \quad \text{for all }C\in \mathcal{C}.$$

Such an $X_0$ exists (by the second part of the proof) and is $P$-a.s. unique, in the sense that if $X'_0$ is another $\mathcal{C}$ measurable integrable numerical random variable with the above property then $X=X_0$ $P$-a.s.

Now what about the case where $X$ is integrable and almost surely non-negative? Strictly speaking we cannot apply Bauer's first result since it concerns only everywhere non-negative random variables. This is why Bauer gives the extra argument at the end of proof.

But we can obtain this result from the first step as follows:

If $X$ is integrable and almost surely non-negative, then we can alter it, and call it say $X'$, on a null set so that $X'$ is measurable, non-negative everywhere and integrable with $\int X' dP=\int X dP$  (setting $X':=0$ on $\{X<0\}\in \mathcal{A}$ will do the job). Hence from the firt part we know there exist a non-negative (everywhere!) numerical random variable $X'_0$ which is $\mathcal{C}$ measurable and has the property

$$\int_C X'_0 \,dP = \int_C X' \,dP =\int_C X \,dP
 \quad \text{for all }C\in \mathcal{C}.$$

The special case $C=\Omega$ says that such an $X'_0$ is in addition integrable. But then from the uniqueness assertion of the second part we know that $X_0=X'_0$ $P$-a.s., that is $X_0\geq 0$  $P$-a.s.